# Docker multiple ports (frontend&backend) not working

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm very new to Docker and CI's so please be don't grill me :)

I'm on Linode and I would like to to run the frontend(react) and backend(python) on the same server. Both will be on separate ports, unless you tell me that this is a wrong approach.

Now, I'm running Jenkins on port `8081` and have two individual jobs:

Backend Jenkins:

```
IMAGE = "my_docker_flask:latest"
image = docker.build("${IMAGE}");
def container = image.run('-p 5000:5000')
def contport = container.port(5000)
```

Backend Dockerfile (flask):

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Frontend Jenkins:

```
IMAGE = "reactapp"
image = docker.build("${IMAGE}")
def container = image.run('-p 6000:6000')
def contport = container.port(6000)
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY build /var/www
```

The backend works fine when I open my Linode's IP with port `5000` but the `6000` does not work. I even tried with `3333` but that does not work either and.

Here's my `docker ps -a`:

```
reactapp  "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   41 seconds ago      Up 40 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6000->6000/tcp
reactapp  "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3333->3333/tcp
my_docker_flask:latest   "python app.py"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
```

Can please someone help me?

How can I run **multiple apps** on different ports using the same IP?

> **EDIT**

I have fixed it but changing to the below:

```
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and

```
def container = image.run('-p 5000:80')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate `does not work` are you unable to route to the react app service, any logs, and errors which you can add here. Does the build folder contain static artifacts such as HTML files?

Comment: when I hit ```mylinodeip:6000``` I get ```This site can’t be reached``` in the browser. how do I find out or check about the build folder files on the server? It is supposed to be just static files. It works locally though.

Comment: I got your problem will post it as an answer if it works for you. The first thing is you cannot use `mylinodeip` as host on your browser because only containers in the network can access through that hostname. I can see that you are exposing the ports outside so please try using `localhost:6000` hopefully it works :)

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding I can hit and see my ```python``` app on ```mylinodeip:5000``` working in the browser on the network, but ```mylinodeip:6000``` or ```mylinodeip:3333``` are not working and I get message ```This site can’t be reached - ERR_UNSAFE_PORT``` nothing to do with my localhost

Comment: I got it :) `80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6000->6000/tcp` observe this so basically you have Nginx serving your application on port 80 but you are mapping port 6000 from container to outside. So try catching your service on port 80 and also map the same port.

Comment: Have only one react app service active.

Answer (score 0):

```
80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6000->6000/tcp
```

Looking at this carefully, we can know that your `reactapp` service is being served at port `80` within the container. But you are trying to map the port `6000` in the container to port `6000` outside. Certainly, you will not be able to access a service where it is not being served at all.

Also, the reason behind `This site can’t be reached - ERR_UNSAFE_PORT` is because you are using the port `6000` which is restricted by the Chrome browser.

Solution:

- map the port 80 only and not any other port as it is being served at.
- stop all other services that are using port 80
- have only one instance of `reactapp` service, as we don't want the other instance to block the port.